# FetchError: request to https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration failed, reason: certificate has expired

Tags: botframework

While using the MS Teams chatbot integration, we are facing issue with the application and it is giving the error in the logs although from local everything works fine :-

JwtTokenExtractor.getIdentity:err! FetchError: request to https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration failed, reason: certificate has expired

Want to know if there is any resolution for this or which certificate do we need renew ?
Thanks !!

Expecting we will be able to hit the end point https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration without any issue.

Comment: I know this question is very old, so I assume you're no longer having this issue? I don't find any certificate issues making requests to that endpoint currently.